# What is the equivalent of ToString("00") in C++?

Tags: c++

What is the equivalent of `.ToString("00")` in C++?

I'm getting an error stating that

```
left of '.ToString' must have class/struct/union
1>        type is 'double'
```

Update: Thanks for the replies, i'm having another similar issue now
//inorder to get //.ToString("00.00000") i did the following

```
  memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
  sprintf_s(buf, "%02.7f",latm); //.7 to match heremisphere
  std::string latm_str = buf;
```

i realised that the %02 doesnt have any effects, example when i get a 7.0, the result is 7.0000000 rather than the desired 07.0000000, anything wrong here?

Comment: "What is English for 'Je suis un rock star'?" is a pretty useless question unless you know that the original phrase is in French :-) What source language is your original in?

Comment: sprintf(string_buffer, "%02d", value)

Comment: What language is `ToString("00");` in? Also `"00"` already looks like a string.

Comment: I thinks its C# and you use it like this:
`double a = 3.14;
string s = a.ToString("00"); // will be 03`

Comment: From the error and its text, I'd guess you are doing `someDouble.ToString( "00" )`.  I don't know where you got this from, but it certainly isn't C++.  In C++, conversions to text are done using `std::ostringstream` (sometimes wrapped in function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double number = 3.14;
char buf[100];
sprintf_s(buf, "%02d", (int)number);
string s = buf;
cout << s; // prints 03
```

Based on [Custom string formatting: ToString("00")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779206/custom-string-formatting-tostring00)

Comment: thanks for your reply, just wondering what if its .ToString("00.00000") ? Do i just need to do a sprintf_s(buf, "%2.5f", number);

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use `std::to_string`

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that this is C# based on [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wch342y(v=vs.110).aspx). If so depending on whether you have access to C++11, you can probably use the following:

```
int a = 3;
std::string s = std::to_string(a);
```

If you're not yet using C++11 then you can use the following:

```
int a = 3;
std::ostringstream ss;
ss.fill('0');
ss << std::setw(2) << a;
std::string s = ss.str();
```

More detail is on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714515/how-can-i-pad-an-int-with-leading-zeros-when-using-cout-operator)

Answer (score 0):

it's `std::to_string` in C++, what you are looking for.

```
double abc = 23.233;
std::string mystring = std::to_string(abc);
```